Touch events in a zoomed UITextView
My app uses a zoomed UITextView. When zoomScale is set anywhere above 1, some touch events are not happening at correct positions.
The gray caret which is where the actual touch happens, and it is also registered correctly both on simulator and on real device, while the blue caret is moving erratically here and there.
With longer texts, the event positions are more and more off towards the bottom, as expected.

Trying to select larger chunks of text makes the scroll view jump and jitter around. Tapping and selecting single words works, but it seems that dragging the cursor around and/or selecting longer chunks of text is when the problem appears.
Here's a very basic project to reproduce the problem:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/smvvr9swgbknejw28n942/ZoomTest.zip?rlkey=m9berh46mumdkyeb6w02r555r&dl=0
You can reproduce this yourself in a blank project by manually setting zoomScale in your view:
textView.zoomScale = 1.3

I'm not sure if this is intended behavior, but I haven't found anything in the documentation about converting the touch events to actually match the physical ones in zoomed views.
What is the indended way to convert the events when zoomScale set, or is this a bug?

While UITextView does inherit from UIScrollView, it is not intended to support .zoomScale. For example, using your basic project, if I set maximumZoomScale = 4.0 and set zoomScale = 4.0, this is the difference: https://i.sstatic.net/yVNerM0w.png ... if you want to support "zooming" a text view, you probably want to take a different approach.

Thank you! This is interesting and confusing, as UITextView even has magnification settings in Interface Builder. Apple shouldn't have hidden the relation between text and scroll views. I'm supporting scaling using a nested full-size text view in scroll view on iPad, but I'll have to figure out another way to do this on iPhone, probably just by using font size.

There are a number of IB settings that appear to show up due to a control's "base" class, but do not seem to affect the control. For your task ... do you want the actual "text content" to scale -- so you can zoom/pan as if it was an image view? Or, do you want the font to change size?

Basically the whole view, and zoomScale scaled it correctly (maintaining insets etc) but because I'm using different layout on iPhone, I was able to set the font, and add proportional scaling to all elements, including line height and so on. It does the trick for now, but it's not ideal: as the text view might hold very long documents, changing the zoom requires a full reformat which takes a while. I'm pretty sure touch events in scaled text views did work at some point though, because I have screen recordings.

Hmm... I suspect it's a difference between TextKit1 and TextKit2 ... in your basic project, add this line: _ = layoutManager as the first line in your awakeFromNib()  and see if you get the behavior you're after.

I'm using TextKit 1 in my main project, which works better than TextKit 2, but not flawlessly. Drawing is off in TK2, while touch events are just as wrong in TK1. I've been knee-deep in TK1 compatibility mode weirdness and filed about a dozen bug reports to Apple, and at this point I'm no longer sure what is intentional behavior and what isn't :-) I made the example in TextKit 2 just in case.
